# Scorm 2004 navigate between SCO

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I'm working on creating a scorm package (2004 3rd Edition) that has several pages within it.  I'm creating a home page that lets you choose which item to navigate to.  However, I'm running into the issue that no form of javascript navigation will work to change to any page.

Using [this package example](http://scorm.com/wp-content/assets/golf_examples/PIFS/SequencingForcedSequential_SCORM20043rdEdition.zip) ([manifest only](http://scorm.com/wp-content/assets/golf_examples/Examples/SequencingForcedSequential/SCORM%202004%203rd%20Edition/imsmanifest.xml)) from the scorm site I've done some testing.  According to the manifest choice mode is enabled.

```
<imsss:controlMode choice="true" flow="true"/>
```

However, whenever I go to the etiquette page then get the API object and attempt any form of navigation, it fails.

```
API.GetValue("adl.nav.request_valid.choice.{target=playing_item}");
API.SetValue("adl.nav.request", "{target=playing_item}choice");
```

After setting the adl.nav.request then the Terminate("") call fails.  The diagnostic is:

```
"Failure calling the Terminate remote callback: the server replied with HTTP Status <div class="notifyproblem">Target Activity does not exist or is unavailable</div>true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Choice mode is enabled, but this rule is likely overriding it.

```
<!--
  'Disabled' will cause the SCO to be visible in the course tree, but not accessible via choice or flow.  
-->
<imsss:ruleAction action="disabled"/>
```

Why not try this feature out with this simple golf example first?

http://scorm.com/wp-content/assets/golf_examples/PIFS/RuntimeMinimumCalls_SCORM20043rdEdition.zip